# Use numpy to get row indexes for a given column value sorted along another column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

The question title may be confusing but here's the problem, I have 2-dimensional numpy arrays. Now, I want to get the list/array of indexes that have a specific value for 1st column while also at the same time sorted along the second column:

```
a = np.array([[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[1,6],[2,9],[1,9],[1,7],[2,7],[1,8]])

index = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 9, 6] # <---- the solution, I want this list

# this list gives sorted array for 1st column value 1
a[index] = 
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [1, 4],
       [1, 5],
       [1, 6],
       [1, 7],
       [1, 8],
       [1, 9]])
```

NOTE: I want the index list, not the sorted array for the given value.

What I've currently come up with is the following:

```
tmp = a[np.lexsort((a[:,1],a[:,0]))]
tmp= tmp[tmp[:,0]==1]
index = [np.where(np.all(a==i,axis=1))[0][0] for i in tmp]
```

As, you can see this is preety bad and as I'm worikng with very large data sets, this needs real improvement. Is there any way to accomplish this more efficiently with numpy?

Comment: you should mark the correct answer if your question was resolved.

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you? Any feedback on posted solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way of doing this using `np.unique`. The advantage with `np.unique` is that you can configure it to return both the indices and the sorted array directly. See code below:

```
# Get the sorted array and indices
tmp = np.unique(a, return_index=True, axis=0)
# Get the indices only where the sorted array's first column equals 1 
index = tmp[1][tmp[0][:,0]==1]
print(index)
```

Output:

```
[0 1 2 3 4 7 9 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`np.lexsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) -

```
# Perform lex-sorting keeping the second col as the primary order.
# Thus, identical elements along that col will be in sequence.
# This helps in keeping unique ones in it later on w/ consecutive checks
In [355]: idx = np.lexsort(a.T)

# Index into the first col with idx, check for the identifier=1
# and then filter out those off idx
In [160]: out = idx[a[idx,0]==1]

In [161]: out
Out[161]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 9, 6])
```

Timings on a large random array -

```
In [167]: np.random.seed(0)    
     ...: a = np.random.randint(0,1000,(100000,2))
     ...: a = np.unique(a,axis=0)
     ...: np.random.shuffle(a)

# @Akaisteph7's soln
In [168]: %%timeit
     ...: tmp = np.unique(a, return_index=True, axis=0)
     ...: index = tmp[1][tmp[0][:,0]==1]
10 loops, best of 3: 48.4 ms per loop

# From this post
In [169]: %%timeit
     ...: idx = np.lexsort(a.T)
     ...: out = idx[a[idx,0]==1]
10 loops, best of 3: 22.1 ms per loop
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate. Where you'r putting the column indexes and where's the value?

Comment: @Eular Think I misunderstood earlier. Edited post. Also, you have stated that you are working with large data. Could you test out how the posted approaches fair at your end?